# Checking UIButton Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to check some UIButton images to see if they are certain images. If they are, I want to set an NSString to a value but the value is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ([self.firstButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]]
    && [self.secondButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image"]]
    && [self.thirdButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image"]]
    && [self.fourthButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image"]]
    && [self.fifthButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image"]]) {
     self.myString = @"some string";
}

NSLog(@"My String: %@", self.myString);
```

Comment: Were your images placed in  Images.xcassets or  app bundle in xcode

Comment: They are in Images.xcassets

Comment: You shouldn't be using your UI to check state. You should use some other data store to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
[[self.firstButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]]
```

Try this one. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing image content isn't a trivial task and comparing handles to memory isn't reliable.

Try converting the images to NSData and compare those with each other.
{

```
NSData * const firstButtonImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.firstButton.currentImage);
NSData * const secondButtonImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.secondButton.currentImage);
NSData * const myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]);
NSData * const anotherImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image"]);

if ([firstButtonImageData isEqualToData:myImageData] &&
        [secondButtonImageData isEqualToData:anotherImageData])
{
    self.myString = @"some string";
}

NSLog(@"My String: %@", self.myString);
```